# Regex a paragraph in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that will match the title to a paragraph and then all of the text in the paragraph from a text file. This paragraph can appear at different parts of the text file but is set-up like this:

*Revenue Recognition*

*\n (blank line)*

*Paragraph of varying length about revenue recognition*

*\n (blank line)*

I'm trying to get the title and then the paragraph. Is there a way to write a regex to end at a blank line?

What I have so far is this:

```
Regex regRev_Rec = new Regex(@"Revenue Recognition(?s).*\n\n(?s).*");
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    foreach (Match recrev in regRev_Rec.Matches(line))
      {
           outputFile.WriteLine(recrev);
      }
}
```

But that doesn't seem close to right.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use the following regex:

```
(?s)(?:^|\n)Revenue Recognition(?:\r?\n){2,}(?<par>.*?)(?:(?:\r?\n){2,}|$)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fs)(%3f%3a%5e%7c%5cn)Revenue+Recognition(%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn)%7b2%2c%7d(%3f%3cpar%3e.*%3f)(%3f%3a(%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn)%7b2%2c%7d%7c%24)&i=line...%0d%0a%0d%0aRevenue+Recognition%0d%0a%0d%0aParagraph%0d%0ahere%0d%0a%0d%0aNew+title+%2f+end)

[image]

The paragraph will be in `recrev.Groups["par"].Value`, here is some sample code (I added `outfile` variable):

```
string file_contents = string.Empty;
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(outfile, false, Encoding.UTF8)) 
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        file_contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    foreach (Match recrev in Regex.Matches(file_contents, @"(?s)(?:^|\n)Revenue Recognition(?:\r?\n){2,}(?<par>.*?)(?:(?:\r?\n){2,}|$)"))
        outputFile.WriteLine(recrev);
}
```

Your solution does not work because you read the file by lines, then check each line, and thus, you do not have a way to match the multiline blocks with a regex. When you read the file to its end, you can use the `RegexOptions.Singleline` (or the inline version `(?s)`) to match whole multiline blocks. The files should not be very long with this approach.

The regex breakdown:

- `(?s)` - enable singleline mode
- `(?:^|\n)` - either start of the string or a newline
- `Revenue Recognition` - matches the literal sequence of chars
- `(?:\r?\n){2,}` - 2 or more linebreaks
- `(?<par>.*?)` - Group holding the paragraph (0+ any characters, as few as possible up to...)
- `(?:\r?\n){2,}` - 2 linebreaks.

Comment: Hi, I know this is many weeks after I originally asked, but your solution has worked! However, I realized that there could be multiple paragraphs under the heading "Revenue Recognition", so what I am trying to do now is to just find "Revenue Recognition" and then grab the next 50 lines regardless of if it has anything to do with revenue recognition. I was wondering how I would modify the regex to match "Revenue Recognition" and then the next 50 lines no matter if it's blank, has characters or has numbers. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You may use `@"(?m-s)^Revenue Recognition.*(?:\r\n.*){0,50}"`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd suggest you to try following code snippet.

```
try
{
    var text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

    var regexObj = new Regex("(?<title>Revenue Recognition)(?:(?:\r?\n){2})(?<paragraph>^.*?(?:(?:\r?\n){2}))",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);

    var match = regexObj.Match(text);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        var title = match.Groups["title"].Value;
        var paragraph = match.Groups["paragraph"].Value;

        Console.WriteLine("Title:\n" + title);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Paragraph:\n" + paragraph.Trim());
    }
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{

}
```

It will print

```
Title:
Revenue Recognition


Paragraph:
Paragraph of varying length about revenue recognition
```

Comment: Capturing a known character sequence is not a good idea though. That is unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Purpose of exercise  is to give idea to OP and help in achieving what they are looking for.

Comment: Well, OP won't achieve anything with this pattern I am afraid. *This paragraph can appear at different parts of the text file* is key here. A code only answer cannot be helpful by definition of a code-only answer.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. I have updated regex and now it's not depending on hard coded sequences and will match Title|Paragraph sequence anywhere in file.

Comment: What is the value you have for your "text" variable? Also, I am looking for just the Revenue Recognition paragraph. I don't need to get every paragraph.

Comment: text variable will hold text from whatever source you have. it could be anything. if you just need first paragraph, it's easy, either remove loop. I'll update it for you.

Comment: Please see updated sample code. Let me know if it worked for you

Comment: It does not work. I think it's because I'm loading the text from a text file, and breaking it up into an array by each line. My other regular expressions are only retrieving one line, while this one is trying to get multiple. These are very long text files so I can't just load the whole thing into one string, and then write a regex to search in that. I'm also seeing that not every file has the exact same format. Thanks for you help though!

Comment: If you see my updated code, I'm reading from file in to a variable, not an array. I'm hopping it should work. See line `var text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);`

Answer (score 0):

```
\A.*
```

Found it here:  [link](http://network.ubotstudio.com/forum/index.php/topic/10919-simply-select-first-line-of-text-file/)

The \A means the match must start at the beginning of the string.
The (.) wildcard means any character except newline (\n).
The asterisk means as many of the preceding as you find, referring to the (.) wildcard.

You could also use: ^.*

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a link the Regex help.

Comment: Please add an explanation as to what this means and how it answers the question.